# Dark water stains on wood

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, water-damage, stain, stain-removal

How do I get dark water stains out of wood? Do I have to sand it? I accidentally left a cup on this Antique wooden buffet and it left a dark round mark that also is kind of white. I'm currently hiding it due to the fact its my fathers. [image: dark wood stain]

Comment: was the cup leaking? ... are you certain that it is from water?

Comment: I wish you the best. You should be honest with your father about this. It's not an easy repair.

Comment: Is this a solid wood surface or just a thin veneer? Can you show us a pic of the edge?

Comment: I would suggest a trip to the [woodworking.se] sister site. There is a _lot_ of info there on refinishing and restoration. You may well learn everything you need to know from answers that already exist. However, knowing what kind of finish it currently has (there are tips on determining that) and whether it's solid wood or a veneer (likely a solid wood, if it's an antique) will still be important things.

Comment: It was a wendys cup with lemonade in it, the cup did leak and its a thick solid piece of wood

Comment: So it may be more than just water - it's sugary water, too. Were you able to find anything at [Woodworking.se] that helped you?

Answer (score -1):

that looks like an iron stain, try oxalic acid.

Comment: I've noticed many of your answers are getting flagged for the Low Quality review queue. I've no doubt that they're correct, but either people, the system, or both think they could use a bit more to make them quality answers. If you could explain a bit _how_ to do the thing you're recommending, it would help your answers a lot.